# How do I combine both queries into a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to move the existing Mysql project to SQL Server. I had to change the queries in PHP because of the engine difference.

Mysql query brings accurate results. But I couldn't convert it to work correctly on the SQL Server side.

I was writing two different queries on SQL Server side and trying to merge them. But I think it's code repetition. How can I convert the following 2 queries into 1 query?

query on the mysql side

```
SELECT Count(*) AS stok_adet, s.*, m.*,d.*
FROM stok AS s 
CROSS JOIN mermer_cins AS m 
JOIN stok_durum AS d 
ON s.stok_durum_id = d.stok_durum_id 
WHERE  m.mermer_cins_id = '5' 
AND s.blok_no = 'M6320' 
GROUP BY s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali
ORDER BY s.blok_no ASC, s.bundle_no ASC, s.stok_tarih DESC
```

---

for stok_adet data - on the SQL Server side

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as stok_adet
FROM stok s
CROSS JOIN mermer_cins m
    JOIN stok_durum d ON s.stok_durum_id = d.stok_durum_id
WHERE m.mermer_cins_id = '5' AND s.blok_no = 'M6320'
GROUP BY s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali;
```

for detail datas - on the SQL Server side

```
SELECT sm.*
FROM (
        SELECT s.*, m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.bundle_no, s.boy, s.yukseklik, s.hatali ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as sequm
        FROM stok s 
        CROSS JOIN mermer_cins m
        WHERE  m.mermer_cins_id = '5' AND s.blok_no = 'M6320'
    ) sm
WHERE sequm = 1
ORDER BY sm.blok_no ASC, sm.bundle_no ASC, sm.stok_tarih DESC
```

---

Sample data on the mysql
[image: related result]

Sample data for stok_adet on the SQL Server
[image: related result]

Sample data for details on the SQL Server
[image: related result]

Comment: Please add some sample data from both table and also your expected output.

Comment: Sample data was uploaded to the topic.

Comment: The first query is defective in terms of SQL, and SQL Server won't allow it. MySQL before version 5.7.5 used to allow that bad syntax, where you could retrieve non-aggregated columns when using `GROUP BY`. I'm specifically talking about `s.*, m.*,d.*`. You'll need to rewrite the MySQL query in standard SQL, or tell us what you want to help you doing it.